# Visual Studio TFS 2015 Web Portal View Project Portal View Process Guidance link doesn't work when left-clicked

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

[image]

When I left-click on View Project portal /process guidance /reports, it doesn't take me to the site.  I need to right-click it and open in new tab or new window.  What could be the problem here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue, please check the comment from Chris Snyder (MSFT) in [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2015/11/30/vs-2015-update-1-and-tfs-2015-update-1-are-available.aspx?utm_medium=twitter&utm_source=twitterfeed) blog:

*"thanks for the heads-up with regards to the Other Links widgets.  The issue you described is a known bug which will be fixed for Update 2.  In the interim, the workaround that we recommend is to craft an instance of the Markdown widget which includes the links you need."*

Comment: Thanks, this was a great help. Look forward to Update 2 but in the meantime the markdown widget works just fine.